# Removing error of looping through columns in a Latex Tabular Environment

Tags: latex, tabular

Hi I am using the following code to try and dynamically set the number of columns in a Latex tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{numcols}
\setcounter{numcols}{4}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
$\loop
\stepcounter{col}
\ifnum \value{col} < \value{numcols}
    c & 
\else
    c
\fi
\ifnum \value{col} = \value{numcols}
    \setcounter{col}{0}
\repeat$
}
\hline
\loop
\stepcounter{col}
\ifnum \value{col} < \value{numcols}
    \textbf{Column \thecol} & 
\else
    \textbf{Column \thecol} \\
\fi
\ifnum \value{col} = \value{numcols}
    \setcounter{col}{0}
\repeat
\hline
\loop
\stepcounter{row}
\ifnum \value{row} < 10
    \loop
    \stepcounter{col}
    \ifnum \value{col} < \value{numcols}
        Cell \therow,\thecol & 
    \else
        Cell \therow,\thecol \\
    \fi
    \ifnum \value{col} = \value{numcols}
        \setcounter{col}{0}
    \repeat
\repeat
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, it throws an error that Illegal pream-token ($): `c' used if I remove the $ I receive the same error but it says Illegal pream-token (\loop):` c' used.

Any help on solving this error would be much appreciated.

I need to create a table with a dynamic number of columns in Latex

Comment: cross-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670764/36296

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a solution has already been provided on [tex.se].